# Raspbian PHP Error

Tags: raspbian, php

I'm building a project that's supposed to connect between my laptop and Raspberry Pi through SSH, it should display data on my Pi's monitor from a database stored on a WAMP server on my laptop. However when I try to open the file in Chromium on the Pi nothing happens. It instead downloads the file as opposed to opening it. Also, when I type in my laptops IP Address i'm presented with an error message reading 'Forbidden. You do not have permission to access / on this server'. This error message is all over the internet but I can't find a working answer anywhere. Can anybody help me? It's pretty urgent I get it working. The code below is my PHP file:

```
<?php
    //Step 1
    $db = mysqli_connect('172.24.1.64', 'root', '', 'hospital') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "hospital";
    $db = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("dbconn");
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $db) or die("mysql");
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            PHP connect to MySQL
        </h1>
        <?php
            //Step 2
            $query = "SELECT * FROM patients;";
            mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

            $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $patientname = $row['patient_name'];                
                $checkindate = $row['check_in_date'];
                $roomnumber = $row['room_number'];
                $bednumber = $row['bed_number'];
                $notes = $notes['notes'];
                echo "$id $patientname $checkindate $roomnumber $bednumber $notes";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure of the following things:

1. Your server (WAMP/APACHE) is running on the laptop.
2. Your file (let's call it index.php) is inside the server folder.(htdocs / www -> your server's root directory.)
3. Try to locally access your file on the laptop's browser using localhost/index.php
4. Check your laptop's IP address and then enter it in your Pi's Browser like so:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.php

---

5. Check the error logs of your server and post in comments if this doesn't help.

Comment: 1. WAMP is running
2. The file is located at the following location: C:\wamp64\www\Hospital
3. I tried and can access the file locally
4. I checked the IP address in CMD -> ipconfig/all -> Ethernet Adapted Ethernet 2 -> IPv4 address. When I typed this into the address bar on the Pi I was given the error ' This server cannot be reached'. I think I'm making a very simple mistake with the IP Address on the pi

Comment: You need to allow port 80 over your firewall to access it over your pi

Comment: how do i do this?

Comment: What Operating system are you using on your laptop?

Comment: Windows 10, Raspbian on the Pi

Comment: What OS on the laptop?

Comment: On my laptop I use Windows 10

Comment: Please go through https://superuser.com/a/665713

Comment: Okay I'll do this and let you know how it goes

Comment: Sure ping me with @

Comment: I followed those steps but it still won't work, saying that I am forbidden from accessing it on this server

Comment: Do one thing make an index.html file inside your WAMP server's main(public) folder and put in hello world in it and try to access it using your laptop's browser itself just test that. The public directory is probably c:\wamp\www

Comment: Yes Index.html works when I do that. My code is: <html>
 <body>
  <p>
   Hello world
  </p>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: That's great now you will also be able to access that for using your IP address on the PI. Simply put your PHP file where you placed index.html

Comment: So what exact web address should I use? I connect my laptop to the Pi hotspot, then go to the Pi browser and go to 192.168.137.1/Index.html ? Is this correct?

Comment: When i try 192.168.137.1 it tells me the address cannot be reached. When i try 172.24.1.64 it tells me I do not have permission to access this from the server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55586/discussion-between-shakti-phartiyal-and-jlally).

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few things...

1. Be sure that the port you are connecting to is allowed.
2. Assuming your file is `index.php`, connect to `<IP>/index.php`.
3. MAKE SURE YOUR FILE IS IN THE CORRECT FOLDER. Otherwise Apache won't serve it!
4. MAKE SURE PHP IS INSTALLED. Execute php -v to check that it is installed and that it is the correct version.

Comment: How can I check if the port is allowed? Sorry a lot of this is new to me

Comment: Never mind :) Just add :8080 like so: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/index.php`

Comment: Check the wamp configuration for which port is being used.. it's probably port 80 bacause you said when you access it gives you a forbidden error.

Comment: Anything in error logs ??

Comment: I tried 192.168.137.1:8080 but the same thing happened 'cannot be reached'. Please see answer below, thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, they are correct.Hm... Did you configure WAMP with some sort of GUI?

Comment: No I just installed WAMP direct from the website

Answer (score 1):

Are these details correct? I entered 192.168.137.1:8080 and nothing happened, below is a screengrab of my cmd when i asked for the IP [image]